# Where can I find income distribution data?

Tags: data-request, economics, income

For any/many countries I'd like to find data on income distribution: for every amount of money, how many people earn that much income.

Alternatively, data representing wealth or other similar values would work as well.

Where can I find such data?

Comment: check sources 3 thru 7 on this page?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_income_equality

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at the world inequality database https://wid.world/ ?